# ngModel binding is not working as expected in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new to Angular5. Playing around the bindings.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `Title : <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="title"  (ngModelChange)="onchange(title)" > {{newtitle}}`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "app";
  newtitle = "";
  onchange(title:any){
    if(title.length < 5){
      this.newtitle = "hello "+title;
    }

  }
}
```

When there is change in ngModel, ngModelchange is perfectly binding value to newtitle variable and working with condition i.e. length < 5.

Now my question is, I want to control the length of the text entering inside the input box.I want input box not to allow the user to enter the length > 5.

I want it to work for type="number", for string it is working for me with maxlength property.

Comment: You can use HTML attribute maxlength => <input maxlength="5" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="title"  (ngModelChange)="onchange(title)" ></input>

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to restrict the enter on an input when the length is more that 5. With validators `max` and `min` you can control the error messages but cannot not prevent the entry of more numbers. 
Instead on `ngModelChange` event use `keypress` event. On that event a method will intercept any key press and if the model value is more that 99999 (so the length is > 5) then it will block its default behaviour. It's important to check its numeric value:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="title" (keypress)="onchange($event)"> 
{{newtitle}}
```

**Typescript:**

```
onchange(event) {
    if (Number(this.title) > 99999) {
      this.newtitle = "Hello " + this.title;    
      event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3tv7p)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`maxlength`** And set to 4:

```
<input maxlength="4" type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" (ngModelChange)="onchange(title)" >
```

For number based inputs:

```
<input max="9999" min="0" type="number" [(ngModel)]="title" (ngModelChange)="onchange(title)" >
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vg6wez?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: maxlength works with string alone right?, I am working with type="number", not able to re-create it. so I have given with type="text".